# How to disable Apple Wireless Trackpad from recovery mode?

Tags: recovery, magic-trackpad

I booted into recovery mode / macOS Utilities and erased my hard drive anticipating to reinstall the OS. Unfortunately my computer is paired to an Apple Wireless Trackpad that I can't find. I believe this trackpad's button is permanently pressed, preventing me from left-clicking, so I can't get all the way through the installer. This trackpad is listed as paired and connected when I go into Terminal and run system_profiler. However recovery mode has no System Preferences so I don't know how to disable this trackpad. Is there any way I can disable the trackpad from recovery mode, such as from Terminal?

Comment: If the trackpad is definitely the culprit, move out of possible Bluetooth range for the device, which is 10 metres (or 32 feet.)

Comment: @IconDaemon Thanks, that's probably the most practical solution. Maybe post that as an answer.

Comment: OK. I made it an answer, but don't accept it unless it proves to be correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the computer to another location a good distance away from where the trackpad may be located. The theoretical maximum distance for Bluetooth is actually far larger than what I thought. See [this page](https://www.sans.edu/cyber-research/security-laboratory/article/bluetooth), and [this one](http://blog.nordicsemi.com/getconnected/things-you-should-know-about-bluetooth-range) for more info about Bluetooth ranges.

Comment: This is what I did and it worked.